# Method not found: 'System.Web.UI.Control System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.get_ContentTemplateContainer()'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, reportviewer

I have reportviewer in aspx in mvc project

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>                           
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="False" Width="800"></rsweb:ReportViewer>            
    </div>
</form>
```

I get this error:

```
 Method not found: 'System.Web.UI.Control System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.get_ContentTemplateContainer()'.
```

`Reportviewer` is referenced. I have this in `web.config`

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
</assemblies>

<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: please provide some code behind, I don't think that your object is declared in the code behind

Comment: The code in .cs is working. This was working in the empty mvc test project that i created to test the report. When i move it to other existing project didn't work. This is what i put in the new project.

Comment: did you copy the whole `.aspx` file over? are the pages connected?

Comment: Yes i just copy the file to the new project and add reference to report viewer.

Comment: have you changed the namespace to match the new project?

Comment: Yes i can build the solution without errors.

Comment: are you using ASP.NET 3.5?